# Maven Build Unresolved Compilation Problem Missing Type

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am converting my application to Maven and I have hit a problem I'm not able to figure out.  The project has no errors in the workspace (eclipse, using m2e plugin), no errors in the build log, and no errors during deploy, but when I try to connect to the server after deploy I get this error:

> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /pages/layout/mainLayout.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> The method getUserDetails&#40;&#41; from the type TrustSSOUtil refers to the missing type OAMAwareUserDetails

OAMAwareUserDetails is an interface that extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails.  I've decompiled the jars to confirm that the class is there and compiled correctly, and the dependency jar (spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE) is contained in the EAR.  Both jars are listed as dependencies in the pom.xml for the WAR and included on the manifest that gets generated from the pom.

My application includes an EAR, a WAR, and several JAR projects.  I can include the poms if someone can let me know which pom is needed.

I realize this question is very similar to others on this site, but I have tried all those that I could find and none of them fixed my issue.

Comment: More plainly, you've verified that the jar containing `OAMAwareUserDetails` is in the .war?

Comment: No, the jar is listed as a dependency in the pom file for the WAR but I am using the <skinnywars> tag so all the jars are put in the EAR instead.  Is this a problem?  How is the skinnywars tag supposed to work?